# I want to compressed image to particular directory

Tags: php

Image was compressed but it will stores in where ever script folder but i want to store image particular given directory.

```
$name = ''; $type = ''; $size = ''; $error = '';
function compress_image($source_url, $destination_url, $quality) {

      $info = getimagesize($source_url);

          if ($info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg')
          $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source_url);

          elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/gif')
          $image = imagecreatefromgif($source_url);

          elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/png')
          $image = imagecreatefrompng($source_url);

          imagejpeg($image, $destination_url, $quality);
          return $destination_url;
        }
     if ($_POST) {
            $upload_image = $_FILES["file"][ "name" ];
            if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
            {
            $error = $_FILES["file"]["error"];
            }
            else if (($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif") ||
            ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") ||
            ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png") ||
            ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")) {

            $url = $upload_image;
           $filename = compress_image($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $upload_image, 80);


           // if(move_uploaded_file($image, $target_dir.$url))
            {
              echo "uploaded success";
            }
        }else {
            $error = "Uploaded image should be jpg or gif or png";
        }
        }
```

Comment: If you ask questions in good english language and additionally explain the problems with your code your question is more likely to be answered.

Comment: sure @Blackbam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
imagejpeg($image, $destination_url, $quality);
```

with

```
imagejpeg($image, "<Your Path>/".$destination_url, $quality);
```

Eg.

```
imagejpeg($image, "uploads/".$destination_url, $quality);
```

Comment: mypath like this i given like it  below not working
$destination_url=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/mysite/uploadimages/';
imagejpeg($image, $destination_url, $quality);